# Wordpress News website, multiple layout, category base?

Tags: wordpress

I have a theme, I am html web designer, but I can understand some php / wordpress coding also

I have a wordpress theme & I want to convert it into a news portal

Please guide me, I want to convert it into category base, should be like that

http://www.firstpost.com/ please guide me, how can I do ?

is it archive page or separate category page?

--

http://www.firstpost.com/category/world

when browsing category page, you can see there are different post layouts

without any duplicate post

please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make a main menu containing links to your categories. This will load in the page you set as post-page (ie. the page that contains your posts).

Go to Appearance - Menu. Create a menu and set it as the main menu.
instead of ticking the boxes for linking to pages, create menu links like www.domain.com/category/cats and www.domain.com/category/dogs

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu